# Passing a function including parameter value to child component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a generic icon class for displaying different types of buttons. I am, however, having trouble getting the Icon class to handle a function passed into it with a specific parameter.

For example, in the scenario below, I have an `Item` class with a toggleEditMode function. I pass this function to the class called `DisplayItem`. In DisplayItem, I once again pass this to the IconButton class with the parameter `true`. I think this is the part that is causing the problem.

When I click on the button I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Icon.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be
>   returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other
>   invalid object.

Here is a sample of what my files look like:

**Class Item**

```
toggleEditMode(editable){
    console.log(editable);
    this.setState({
        edit_mode: editable
    });
}

render(){
    if (!this.state.edit_mode){
        return (
            <DisplayItem toggleEditMode={this.toggleEditMode.bind(this)} />
        )
    } else {
        return <EditItem />
    }
}
```

**Class DisplayItem**

```
render(){
    return (
        <div><IconButton type="edit" onClick={()=>{this.props.toggleEditMode(true)}} /></div>
    )
}
```

**Class IconButton**

```
render(){
    if (this.props.type == "edit"){
        return <span style={edit} onClick={()=>{this.props.onClick()}}>Edit</span>
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pointing to your `IconButton` render. Explicitly return `null` when you don't want it to render anything:

```
render(){
  if (this.props.type == "edit"){
    return <span style={edit} onClick={()=>{this.props.onClick()}}>Edit</span>
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```